# My jsonParser not working correctly?

Tags: android

I am trying to add the record in database using android application as a front-end and php as a back-end but while i am trying to add below

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);
```

In above line jsonParser cannot resolved symbols
    can anyone help to solve this error in android studio

This is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domore.allinone"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'org.json:json:20141113'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1'
}
```

If you are watching full code then click on this link

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: Have you added `JSONParser` class in project? `jsonParser ` is object of `JSONParser` class so create it as `JSONParser jsonParser =new JSONParser(); `

Comment: @Millu, sync your gradle.

Comment: Please check JSON response (Listing all Products in above mentioned link).If your are getting wrong format json result then will get this error.

Answer (score 0):

makeHttpRequest function code

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
```

DefaultHttpClient is removed in android api 23.use HttpURLConnection

```
  HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```